# What does 経つ mean with 結構?

Tags: translation

I just saw this phrase in a book I bought.

> 結構経ちました

This sounds vague to me. I also couldn't find a definition on a dictionary.

I've found this example though there are also others. https://www.tripadvisor.com/LocationPhotoDirectLink-g298224-d1373583-i54141525-Kokusaidori-Naha_Okinawa_Prefecture.html

Does this phrase literally mean "time passed well"? Does that just mean the speaker had fun?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your example,

> わしたショップも出来て結構経ちました

it’s “**Quite a bit of time has passed** since わしたショップ opened here (too/even).” — or even technically it could be “**Quite a bit of time has passed** (since I was last here), with even わしたショップ opening.” (The scoping of the adverbial clause is a little ambiguous.)

Comment: So what happens if I use this with a verb? Like for example: 出して結構経ちました? Does it mean "it's been a while since I (performed the verb)?

Comment: I think it works better with intransitive verbs like できる, because with transitive verbs (like 出す) there’s an awkward grammatical structure where you switch from an animate subject / actor in the first half of the sentence to an inanimate subject / patient in the second half.

Comment: (You can understand the subject of 経つ to be 時間 if you want, though I’d say the verb does function on its own and it’s not exactly just an omission.)